# Is there any way to take screenshots of hundreds of lines of code from within an IDE? Specifically Java and C# colouring

Tags: c#, java, ide, screenshot

I have been print screening and pasting multiple screens into photoshop so far, but there must be an easier way?

Comment: http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&q=take+scroll+bar+window+screen+shot&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Comment: Can I ask why do you do that?

Comment: There exist some tool which will let you get the screen shot of particular window even it is scrollable try them

Comment: I want to show the code and to dissuade users from resorting to copypasta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Ducklink software](http://www.ducklink.com/p/free-screen-capture-tool/) for screen

Comment: I recommend [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/ "ShareX - Screen capture, file sharing and productivity tool") instead. Much better

Comment: DuckLink link now is anavailable.

Answer (score 4):

What about an pdf-printer-driver ?

Comment: Has anyone **tried** this before upvoting?! Printing in Visual Studio kills all the formatting, changes the font to Courier New and prints it in all black...

Comment: Notepad++ preserves the syntax highlighting when printing.

Comment: @JRL Not only that, but it also keeps Dark Theme mode on when exporting `PDF`! One more proof that Notepad++ is superior to Visual Studio. Check out my [Notepad++ MSVC C++ IDE](https://github.com/ScienceDiscoverer/npp_msvc_ide), if you are interested in ditching Visual Studio for good!

Comment: Note: to enable Dark Mode background printing into PDF go into Notepad++ `Preferences` -> `Print` -> `Colour Options`. Pick `WYSIWYG`. Also disable line number printing. It's buggy and will have white background.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio, you can just copy and paste the source. If you paste it into any rich-text enabled software — e.g., Microsoft Word — the code will be formatted the same way as it is in Visual Studio, with all fonts, colours and bold styles intact.

Once you’ve pasted it into Word, you can do with it whatever you want, including printing to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

If you have extra money to spent, [SnagIT](http://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.asp) is worth the price.

It comes with a very intuitive image editor.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I found a usable workaround to use Jetbrains' Project Rider to export a source file to HTML, and then use Firefox's fullscreen screenshot feature to capture the screen.

This gave me a screenshot that was higher resolution than the IDE text editor, and contained the whole file (which was what I wanted, to show the levels of indentation and spaghetti-ness of the code) in a file approximately 2k x 6k pixels.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you take screenshots for printing out code??

Just open your file in Visual Studio, Eclipse, Notepad++ and select File - Print and you'll get your file with a nice coloring (when using a color printer).

If you need it as a hard-copy on your screen just take [FreePDF](http://freepdfxp.de/) to print it into a pdf file.

#### Update

I tested it right now with the above PDF printer driver and it comes out just as expected. So i think you just using a Bulls**t pdf printer driver.

Comment: -1: Visual Studio doesn’t print in colour. It doesn’t even use boldface.

Comment: @Timwi - Visual Studio does print in colour, if a colour printer is available to it (just tried in 2008). Whether the PDF printer drivers support colour printing is another matter entirely.

Comment: @Damien: Then how do I enable this? I specifically chose “Color” in my PDF printer (Bullzip) and yet the result is all black (and no boldface either).

Comment: Just tried it in 2010 and it's courier/black&white. Which makes sense, seeing as my background color is black.